# How to get the position of a key in a Python ordered dictionary efficiently?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ordereddict

I am trying to calculate the miss ratio curve for an LRU cache. I have implemented the cache as an ordered dictionary. whenever I add a key to the cache, to find the previous location of the key in the cache, I have to create a list of dictionary keys and index them.

Having a huge number of keys (around 10,000,000), this method obviously is very slow.
Is there a faster way to find the location of the key in an ordered dictionary?
Or do you suggest using another structure instead of an ordered dictionary to implement the cache?

Comment: Maybe you could provide an example with just a few entries. It's not clear (at least to me) why you need to know the location of the key. That seems to defeat the purpose of using a hash table. Is the order significant? Is it sorted? (which would lend itself to faster searches). Can you add a reference to the previous key? etc...

Comment: To calculate the miss ration curve, I need to find the usage distance of the key (the number of unique keys that have been accessed from the previous access of the current key). In an LRU cache, this is equal to the number of keys from the head of the cache to the current location of the key.

Comment: You probably want to store the position of the item in the value part of your entry if you need a fast lookup.

Comment: @Kraigolas thanks. I thought about it but the problem is whenever a key is accessed, it will be moved to the head of the cache and therefore the location of all the other keys will be changed. So I have to update all the values.